# Strange behaviours in CCCrypt iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am facing a strange behaviour in encryption and decryption using SWIFT 3
.I am using the following method to encrypt and decrypt a string.While encryption I an generating a random salt and apending it to the end of the encrypted data and while decryption I am reading the IV data from the data to decrypt and performing the decrypt operation.

```
internal func cryptography(_ inputData: Data, key: String, operation: CCOperation) -> Data? {

    //prepare the Key
    let keyData: Data!    = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    let keyBytes          = keyData.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in
        return bytes
    }
    let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)

    //Prepare the input data

    //Check whether this is encryption , if so generate a random  IV and append this to the encrypted data
    let ivBuffer:UnsafePointer<UInt8>?
    let dataBytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>?
    var dataLength :Int? = 0
    var ivData :Data? = nil
    if (operation == CCOperation(kCCEncrypt)){

        ivData = self.generateIV()
        ivBuffer = (ivData == nil) ? nil : ivData!.withUnsafeBytes({ (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in
            return bytes
        })
        dataBytes        = inputData.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in
            return bytes
        }
        dataLength = Int(inputData.count)
    }
    else{

        //for decryption the last 16 bytes will be the IV so extract it
        var dataToProcess  = inputData
        let rangStart = inputData.count - kCCBlockSizeAES128
        let rangeEnd = rangStart + kCCBlockSizeAES128
        var range = Range(rangStart..<rangeEnd)
        ivData = inputData.subdata(in:range)
        ivBuffer = ivData?.withUnsafeBytes({ (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in
            return bytes
        })

        range = Range(0..<rangStart)
        dataToProcess = inputData.subdata(in: range)
        dataBytes        = dataToProcess.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in
            return bytes
        }
        dataLength = Int(dataToProcess.count)
    }


    //Calculate buffer details
    var bufferData       = Data(count: Int(dataLength!) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    let bufferPointer    = bufferData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> in
        return bytes
    }
    let bufferLength     = size_t(bufferData.count)


    var bytesDecrypted   = Int(0)
    let tst = CCCryptorStatus()
    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(
        operation,                      // Operation
        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES128),   // Algorithm is AES
        CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding), //options
        keyBytes,                       // key data
        keyLength,                      // key length
        ivBuffer,                            // IV buffer
        dataBytes,                      // input data
        dataLength!,                     // input length
        bufferPointer,                  // output buffer
        bufferLength,                   // output buffer length
        &bytesDecrypted)                // output bytes decrypted real length
    if Int32(cryptStatus) == Int32(kCCSuccess) {
        bufferData.count = bytesDecrypted // Adjust buffer size to real bytes




        if (operation == CCOperation(kCCEncrypt)){

            bufferData.append(ivData!)
        }
        return bufferData as Data
    } else {
        print("Error in crypto operation: \(cryptStatus)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now comes the strange behaviour.
I am calling this method twice , first for encryption and second for decryption of encrypted string returned from the previous call.

Now If I run this code then encryption will happen successfully , but decryption is returning invalid data - cryptStatus here is success but the bytesDecrypted is showing as 16 and converting this tostring is returning nil.

Now the strange thing is ,if I put a breakpoint at the else part of encryption (i.e methods extracting IV from encrypted String) , ie on the last line of the following, then if print  dataToProcess and  ivData to console using po , then decryption is happening correctly.

```
//for decryption the last 16 bytes will be the IV so extract it
    var dataToProcess  = inputData
    let rangStart = inputData.count - kCCBlockSizeAES128
    let rangeEnd = rangStart + kCCBlockSizeAES128
    var range = Range(rangStart..<rangeEnd)
    ivData = inputData.subdata(in:range)
    ivBuffer = ivData?.withUnsafeBytes({ (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in
        return bytes
    })

    range = Range(0..<rangStart)
    dataToProcess = inputData.subdata(in: range)
    dataBytes        = dataToProcess.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in
        return bytes
    }
    dataLength = Int(dataToProcess.count)
```

Any idea about this strange behaviour.Do I need to do any reset or give any delay??

Comment: An update ..The text is decrypting correctly if I print out (po) only the "dataToProcess" variable, Still confused ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are bad in your code are all these usages of `withUnsafeBytes` or `withUnsafeMutableBytes`:

```
    let keyBytes          = keyData.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in
        return bytes
    }
```

Check the reference of `withUnsafeBytes`:

[withUnsafeBytes(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes)

> #### Warning
>
> The byte pointer argument should not be stored and used outside of the lifetime of the call to the closure.

(You can find the same warning for [`withUnsafeMutableBytes`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779823-withunsafemutablebytes).)

All your usages of `withUnsafeBytes` or `withUnsafeMutableBytes` are bringing the pointer argument outside the closure, which may cause any sort of unexpected behaviors including just crashing.

The right usage of `withUnsafeBytes` or `withUnsafeMutableBytes` is something like this:

```
func cryptography(_ inputData: Data, key: String, operation: CCOperation) -> Data? {
    
    //prepare the Key
    let keyData = key.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    let keyLength = kCCKeySizeAES128
    
    //Prepare the input data
    
    //Check whether this is encryption , if so generate a random  IV and append this to the encrypted data
    let ivData :Data
    let data: Data
    if operation == CCOperation(kCCEncrypt) {
        ivData = self.generateIV()
        data = inputData
    } else {
        //for decryption the last 16 bytes will be the IV so extract it
        let rangStart = inputData.count - kCCBlockSizeAES128
        let rangeEnd = inputData.count
        ivData = inputData.subdata(in: rangStart..<rangeEnd)
        data = inputData.subdata(in: 0..<rangStart)
    }
    let dataLength = data.count
    
    //Calculate buffer details
    var bufferData       = Data(count: dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    let bufferLength     = bufferData.count
    
    var bytesDecrypted   = 0
    let cryptStatus = keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
        ivData.withUnsafeBytes {ivBuffer in
            data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
                bufferData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {bufferPointer in
                    CCCrypt(
                        operation,                      // Operation
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES128),   // Algorithm is AES
                        CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding), //options
                        keyBytes,                       // key data
                        keyLength,                      // key length
                        ivBuffer,                            // IV buffer
                        dataBytes,                      // input data
                        dataLength,                     // input length
                        bufferPointer,                  // output buffer
                        bufferLength,                   // output buffer length
                        &bytesDecrypted)                // output bytes decrypted real length
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if cryptStatus == Int32(kCCSuccess) {
        bufferData.count = bytesDecrypted // Adjust buffer size to real bytes
        if operation == CCOperation(kCCEncrypt) {
            bufferData.append(ivData)
        }
        return bufferData
    } else {
        print("Error in crypto operation: \(cryptStatus)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent Thanks a lot :)